# Celery: does the worker stop at maximum capacity?

Tags: celery

I set concurrency to 10 on a small server.

I submitted 20 jobs on it, I expected 10 to run, but it never went beyond 5 concurrency.

Why is this happening and is Celery automatically limiting itself based on the memory and cpu?

I add that its a small server 512mb ram running video transcoding operation (ffmpeg)

Comment: I don't know why it's happening. But if you set `concurrency` to 20, it will run 10 jobs at a time.

Comment: concurrency is set to 10. so is the actual # of jobs half of that amount??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check your [CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#std:setting-CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER) configuration

> The default is 4

It means that all your 10 threads will pre-fetch 4 and run them one by one

```
 # Send 20 tasks
 worker-1: prefetch 4 tasks: 1-4 
 worker-2: prefetch 4 tasks: 5-8
 worker-3: prefetch 4 tasks: 9-12
 worker-4: prefetch 4 tasks: 13-16
 worker-5: prefetch 4 tasks: 17-20
 worker-6: no more tasks to fetch
 worker-7: no more tasks to fetch 
 worker-8: no more tasks to fetch 
 worker-9: no more tasks to fetch
 worker-10: no more tasks to fetch
```

Preftech is usefull to limit network use, if tasks are very fast to complete it reduces greatly communication between the broker and the worker and boost performance.

But if task are slow it will unbalance workers loads.

edit:

For your case (task ~30 minutes) use prefetch=1.

Also bench using 10 celery process with 1 thread (concurency=1) instead of 1 proces with 10 threads (concurency=10), it can perform a little bit better.

More info in this doc:
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits

Comment: most of my takes at least 30 minutes or more. whats the optimal way?? Also not sure I understand how pre-fetch being 4 ends up running only 5 jobs at a time. shouldn't it run 4 at a time? Concurrency is set to 10 but I believe number of pool process is unchanged.

Comment: prefetch is how many tasks/messages the worker fetch from rabbitmq. 
Then the worker will process them one by one.
your 5 first wokers clean up the queue. As explained worker 1 will process task 1/2/3/4 but one after another.

Comment: by worker do you mean celery worker or a process? To be clear I have one celery worker running on 1 server box. I have rabbitmq on another server. I plan on adding more celery workers. I'm trying to make each celery worker server run 10 jobs at a time. I'm guessing that if I submit 100 jobs in the future and I have 2 celery worker servers, each would get 50 jobs queued and work through it's own queue 5 at a time?

Comment: By worker I mean one of your 10 threads. 
With two servers you will have 20 workers. If you submit 100 jobs with prefetch 4, 80 jobs will be prefetch, 20 will be processed simultaneously by your 20 workers, and the last 20 jobs will still wait in your rabbitmq for a worker to be free.

Comment: But In your case, I repeat use prefetch=1. 
Same exemple but with prefetch=1 ->
20 jobs will be fetch/20 processed/80 waiting in the rabbitmq queue

Comment: That part makes sense now. It would be bad for a prefetch to be bigger than one because it won't be in the rabbitmq to be processed by other available servers. `Also bench using 10 celery process with 1 thread (concurency=1) instead of 1 proces with 10 threads (concurency=10), it can perform a little bit better.` how would that improve performance? each job requires a third party binary executable to be launched (10 jobs = 10 instances of 3rd party software). Also, is it possible to define the prefetch=1 in the command argument? Sort of like how I set concurrency=10 when I launch celery worker